# How can i create variable from string in R (API data)?

Tags: r, api

I receive data from API in R. Below is an example answer:

```
"top3": {
        "2015-09-14": 856293,
        "2015-09-21": 860175,
        "2015-09-28": 855798,
        "2015-10-05": 853955,
        "2015-10-12": 841631,
        "2015-10-19": 837971,
        "2015-10-21": 837025,
        "2015-10-26": 833868,
        "2015-11-02": 831811,
        "2015-11-09": 833887,
        "2015-11-16": 835176,
        "2015-11-23": 807198,
        "2015-11-30": 797527,
        "2015-12-07": 793526,
        "2015-12-14": 815146,
        "2015-12-21": 799419,
        "2015-12-28": 815103,
        "2016-01-04": 813964,
```

Then I transfer this data to dataset. Code below:

```
raw_data <- getURL("URL of query")
  #Zapisujemy dane w JSon
  json_file <- fromJSON(raw_data)
  #przerabiamy dane na data set
  json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
         x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
         unlist(x)
     })
  #Robimy data frame
  table_statistics <- as.data.frame(json_file, row.names = NULL)
```

Then function `str(dataset)` look like that:

```
'data.frame':   132 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ top3 : int  856293 860175 855798 853955 841631 837971 837025 833868 831811 833887 ...
 $ top10: int  2152606 2160720 2152531 2159136 2162571 2161058 2124578 2115109 2113461 2112437 ...
 $ top50: int  5665937 5681734 5669705 5704516 5719911 5724953 5540973 5453949 5459164 5468059 ...
```

How can I transfer the date into variable? What I'm trying to do is creating graph where x = date, y = top3/top10/top50.

Comment: Please post a small but valid raw_data, and indicate the package containing `fromJSON` (jsonlite ?)

Comment: @digEmAll Raw_Data: '> raw_data
[1] "{\n    \"top3\": {\n        \"2015-09-14\": 856293,\n        \"2015-09-21\": 860175,\n        \"2015-09-28\": 855798,\n        \"2015-10-05\": 853955,\n        \"2015-10-12\": 841631,\n        \"2015-10-19\": 837971,\n        \"2015-10-21\": 837025,\n        \"2015-10-26\": 833868,\n        \"2015-11-02\": 831811,\n        \"2015-11-09\": 833887,\n        \"2015-11-16\": 835176,\n        \"2015-11-23\": 807198,\n        \"2015-11-30\": 797527,\n        \"2015-12-07\": 793526,\n'. I used: library(RJSONIO)

Comment: you can retrieve the dates using `names(x)` in your function. hard to test without any data.